# If a card reader + its driver are PC/SC compliant in windows, is it PC/SC compliant in Ubuntu?

Tags: smartcard, pcscd

I have two basic questions and find no one and nowhere to ask them. finally send them to you.

1. If a card reader+ its driver was PC/SC compliant in windows, is it PC/SC compliant in other OSs too? (for example in Linux, MacOS and ...). Or for each OS we need a new test?
2. If I have a card reader and I don't want to trust its factory and the list that is in  the PC/SC workgroup site, can I myself check its compatibility with PCSC or not? 
   I mean, is there any check list to checking?

I would appreciate a detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the reader is CCID compliant, it would appear that the answer is yes. From http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid.html#CCID_compliant:

> The USB CCID specification published by the USB Workgroup aims to normalize USB smartcard readers, in order to have a single driver (supplied once for all with the operating system) for virtually any reader from any manufacturer.
>
> PCSC-Lite project includes an open source CCID driver. This driver has been tested with SpringCard CSB6 on GNU/Linux, and should work on the other operating systems targetted by the project.

Since PCSC-Lite is pc/sc compliant, and CCID is included, this should imply that all CCID compliant readers can be used in PCSC-Lite, a PC/SC compliant driver. http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/

1. Per http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid.html#CCID_compliant

> To know if a smart card reader is CCID compliant and should be supported by this driver but is not listed bellow
>
> Just get the source code of this driver and do:

```
tar xjvf ccid-x.y.z.tar.bz2
cd ccid-x.y.z
./configure
make
sudo ./src/parse > output.txt
```